# In python, how to generate random sampling without replacement of a specific column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Input data looks somewhat like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'users': ['John', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'John', 'Alice','Bob','Alice'], 
                   'class': ['Economics','Economics','Economics','Maths','Maths','Physics','Physics']})
```

The random data should be generated such that `class` will not be replaced but `users` can be replaced.

```
random_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'users': ['John', 'Bob', 'Alice'], 
                   'class': ['Economics','Maths','Physics']})
or 
random_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'users': ['John', 'John', 'Bob'], 
                   'class': ['Economics','Maths','Physics']})
```

Comment: your `random_df` contains all unique values from colum `class`?

Comment: yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) to get the unique values in column `class` then create a new dataframe with `users` (within a given class) randomly selected using [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame([
    {'users': np.random.choice(df.loc[df['class'].eq(c), 'users']), 'class': c}
    for c in df['class'].unique()])
```

Result:

```
print(df_)
   users      class
0   John  Economics
1  Alice      Maths
2  Alice    Physics
```

Comment: If you refer to the original dataset 'Bob' was never assigned to 'Maths'. If it's randomly selected, it tend to assign Bob to Maths which is not possible.

Comment: @Sara-swathy So you want to randomly select data(`users`) within a given class, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` on `class` column and then use `sample` method to randomly select samples from particular `class`

```
df = df.groupby("class").apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   users      class
0    Bob  Economics
1  Alice      Maths
2    Bob    Physics
```

Comment: This works perfect for small dataset, Is there any scalable approach for larger dataset? Say, I have a dataset of 15K rows.